# Partial derivatives of particular function at $(0,0)$

Tags: limits

Let
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
x^2 &  \text{si $|x|<|y|$}\\
y^2  &   \text{si $|x|\geq|y|$}
\end{cases}$$

My question is: calculate Partial derivatives  at $(0,0)$.

My answer is:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2-0}{x}=0$$
such that $(x,y)$ is inthe set $|x|<|y|$.
But for:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{y^2-0}{x}=?$$

such that $(x,y)$  in the set  $|x|\geq|y|$.

Comment: That doesn't  make sense. Notice $f(x,0) = 0$ and $f(0,y)=0$.

Comment: @user251257 . You are correct. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}=\begin {cases} 2x&|x| < |y|\\ 0& |x| > |y| \end {cases}$

That is the easy part.

What about $|x| = |y|$

If $2x \ne 0$ the derivative does not exist.

and finally, what about $(0,0)$?

In that case $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x} = 2x = 0$

Comment: Then for all $(x,y)=(a,a)$  the partial derivatives do not exist?

Comment: That is correct,  Think of this region as the intersection of two parabolic cylinders.  Where the cylinders intersect, the the surface is not differentiable.  If you made a picture of the surface, you would see that there is an edge.